# I'm trying to print the results of my arrays to the console, but I can't access the functions inside the class. what can we do

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, for-loop, oop

I'm trying to print the results of my arrays to the console, but I can't access the functions inside the class. what can we do.

**This is the result I want. But arranged according to oop principles**

```js
let arrya = [];
let arryb = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
  function crad_a(max) {
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    return a;
  }
  // console.log(crad_a(10));

  function crad_b(max) {
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    return b;
  }
  // console.log(crad_b(10));
  i++;

  arrya.push(crad_a(10));
  arryb.push(crad_b(10));
}
console.log(arrya);
console.log(arryb);

for (let j = 0; j <= arrya.length; j++) {
  if (arrya[j] != arryb[j]) {
    if (arrya[j] > arryb[j]) {
      console.log("a" + " " + "win" + " " + " the game");
    } else {
      console.log("b" + " " + "win" + " " + "the game");
    }
  }
}
```

## **This is what I tried and got stuck**

```js
class card_number_one {
  constructor() {
    this.card_one = [];
    this.card_tow = [];
  }
  
  crad_a(max) {
    for (let d = 0; d <= 9; d++) {
      a = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      return a;
    }
    d++;
    this.card_one.push(crad_a(10));
  }
  
  crad_b(max) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      b = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      return b;
    }
    i++;
    this.card_tow.push(crad_b(10));
  }
}

console.log(this.card_one); /// Not working for me
```

Comment: `this` outside of class `card_number_one` points to `window` object(Also depends whether you are running it on a browser or server(node.js) or whether you are in strict mode or not). Maybe acquire some knowledge on how `this` works in JavaScript? MDN is a great place to start. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes it should help you solve this one. What I notice however;

Classes must be defined before they can be constructed

```
 // Defining your class
 class Card {
    // stuff
 }
         
 // Constructing your class
 let foo = new Card();
```

Then afterwards you can do a log of foo:

```
console.log(foo)
```

1. Its good practice to use pascal notation over camel notation when defining your class, so class Card instead of class cardName.
2. I am not 100% sure what your method is doing but try to keep your code [DRY](https://dzone.com/articles/is-your-code-dry-or-wet#:%7E:text=DRY%20code%20is%20a%20software,t%20adhere%20to%20DRY%20principle.) so instead of having 2 for loops, you can have one method which you can reuse.

So in your case that would be:
ps:// I also changed your method to a getter, you can read more avout getters here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

```
class Card {
  constructor(array, max) {
    this.array = array;
    this.max = max;
  }
  get maxNumber(){
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.max; i++) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.max);
    }
  }

}

let array1 = [1,2,3,4];
let array2 = [5,6,7,8];

let card1 = new Card(array1, 10)
let card2 = new Card(array2, 20)

console.log(card1.maxNumber); // Returns 7
console.log(card2.maxNumber); // Returns 6

let difference = card1.maxNumber - card2.maxNumber // Assuming the number doesn't have to be greater than 0.

// Print your message
console.log(`Your game score is ${difference}, good job!`);
```

So now you have a reusable class, which you can use to load as many cards as you want :)

Comment: Thank you very much. For the answer, it basically works, I will learn from it and try to develop it for my project

Comment: You are welcome, I also learnt about classes not so long ago. Keep going, you are doing great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `console.log()` call the `this` does not refer to the class (it is outline the class).

You could create an instance of the class, and then log the property of the instance, something like this:

```js
class card_number_one {
  constructor() {
    this.card_one = [];
    this.card_tow = [];
  }
  crad_a(max) {
    for (let d = 0; d <= 9; d++) {
      a = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      return a;
    }
    d++;
    this.card_one.push(crad_a(10));
  }
  crad_b(max) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      b = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      return b;
    }
    i++;
    this.card_tow.push(crad_b(10));
  }
}

// Create an instance of the class and save it in the "exampleCard" variable
const exampleCard = new card_number_one();

// Console log the property "card_one" of the "exampleCard" instance of your class
console.log(exampleCard.card_one);
```

There is some good information about JS classes [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)